# fails to label x by its values in a pandas bar plot

Tags: pandas, plot

The following code fails to shows the Ref values 'F', 'C', 'H', 'B', 'G', 'A', 'D', 'E'. Only index values are shown:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'Ref': ['F', 'C', 'H', 'B', 'G', 'A', 'D', 'E'],
                     'Nombre Pieces': [150, 130, 100, 60, 30, 30, 20, 10],
                     'PC100': [28.301887, 52.830189, 71.698113, 83.018868, 88.679245, 94.339623, 98.113208, 100.000000],
                     'categories': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']})

colors = {'a': 'red', 'b': 'blue'}

data['PC100'].plot(kind='bar', color=data['categories'].map(colors))

plt.show()
```

How to edit this code? Thanks

Comment: `data.set_index('Ref')['PC100'].plot(kind='bar', color=data['categories'].map(colors))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only plot:

```
data.set_index('Ref')['PC100'].plot(kind='bar', color=data['categories'].map(colors))
```

For permanent index change on your dataframe and plot:

```
data.set_index('Ref', inplace=True)
data['PC100'].plot(kind='bar', color=data['categories'].map(colors))
plt.show()
```

The result is same when you plot with the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Not that easy.

Comment: @Jean-Pat No problem Jean, I am very happy that you have solved your problem, if you run into futrher problems you can message me and I will help further :) Have a great day